# postgres avg query

Tags: sql, postgresql

Не могу понять даже как составить, есть 3 таблицы

```
Templates /

id name


Products /

id template_id delivery_cost


Modifications /

id product_id price
```

У меня есть tempalte_id и зная его нужно узнать все products и среднее значение modifications + shipping_cost товара

У меня вышло вот что:

```
SELECT *, (
           (SELECT avg(dp.price)
            FROM (
                     SELECT ppm.price as price
                     FROM producer_products
                              LEFT JOIN modifications ppm
                                        on producer_products.id = ppm.product_id
                     WHERE products.template_id = 385
                     GROUP BY ppm.product_id, ppm.price
                 ) as dp
           ) + (
               SELECT avg(products.shipping_cost) as scost
               FROM products
               WHERE products.template_id = 385
           )
    ) as price
FROM products
WHERE products.template_id = 385
```

Что дает совсем не то среднее значение, оно высчитывает среднее включая модификации не одного конкретного товара, а сразу всех. Подскажите как решить это

Comment: В описании структуры таблиц нет shipping_cost, а в запросе он есть. И не ясно зачем вы вычисляете его среднее по всем продуктам. Он же судя по вашему запросу один на один продукт. А значит надо посчитать средний price и уже к нему добавить единственный shipping_cost. Так ?

Comment: Замените описание таблиц на их CREATE TABLE. Дайте пример данных (в виде INSERT INTO) и требуемый результат для именно этих данных с пояснением, почему именно так. И укажите точную версию СУБД.